# quiet splash boot on Raspberry Pi 4 / 19.10.1

Tags: boot, pi-4, ubuntu

Where do I enable "quiet splash" for booting my Raspberry Pi 4b on Ubuntu 19.10.1? Should it be on the Micro SD card or in the filesystem? I've made changes to grub without success. Does 19.10 even use grub or does it use uboot?